# What is the correct term for the exterior of a rocket or space launch system?

Tags: rockets, terminology

Would you call it the casing, cladding, exterior structure, hull, shell...?

Comment: Depends on what you’re trying to say about it. “Skin” comes up a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It's sometimes (often) referred to as the [Outer Mold Line](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20120017909.pdf), which always seemed a bit odd to me, because it's not molded, usually.

Comment: I always wondered where that term comes from...

Comment: Outer Mold Line is a term from metal manufacturing, it is the contour of the outside of a metal part (https://cr4.globalspec.com/thread/80869/Inner-and-Outer-Mold-Line-Definition-in-Sheet-Metal-Operation). For stamped sheet metal, this is the shape of the outer mold.